# How to do random sampling based on customer ID

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have a data set as below

```
Cust_ID SubDepartment       Date        Bill_Value
1513    Detergent Bars      20180204    30
1513    French Fries        20180803    160
1513    Fruit Based Juices  20180204    30
1513    Containers          20180803    79
1513    Candies & Lollypops 20180803    165
1513    Cheese              20180204    203.04
1513    Cleaners & Wipers   20180803    159
1513    Chocolates          20180803    448
1513    Frozen Veg Snacks   20180803    570
1860    Salted Biscuits     20180110    40
1860    Oats                20180705    60
1860    Pastries            20180815    198
1860    Cheese              20180110    85
1860    Veg Powdered Soups  20180814    20
1860    Paneer              20180123    99
1860    North Indian Mixes  20180502    59
1860    Flavoured Milk      20180502    40
```

[sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9BQ.jpg)

I have want to do random sampling of the data based on customer id such that it picks all the transaction of the selected customers

Comment: am trying to do in R , expected output is when i do random samples it should pick all the transactions done by the customer . If should not miss any transaction for selected Cust_ID

Comment: Can you post the expected output? An example would make it more clear.

Comment: Cust_ID SubDepartment       Date        Bill_Value
1513    Detergent Bars      20180204    30
1513    French Fries        20180803    160
1513    Fruit Based Juices  20180204    30
1513    Containers          20180803    79
1513    Candies & Lollypops 20180803    165
1513    Cheese              20180204    203.04
1513    Cleaners & Wipers   20180803    159
1513    Chocolates          20180803    448
1513    Frozen Veg Snacks   20180803    570 .                                   
  Random sampling should not leave any of the transaction done by the customer on different dates/products

Comment: please add "one possible" outcome to your question.

Answer (score 4):

here is a simple solution where you first get all unique ids, sample them and subset the data frame based on the sample:

```
df[df$Cust_ID %in% sample(unique(df$Cust_ID), n),]
```

where `n` is the number of `id` to sample.

With your data:

```
 set.seed(1) #to be reproducible  
 df[df$Cust_ID %in% sample(unique(df$Cust_ID), 1),]
```

## output

```
  Cust_ID       SubDepartment     Date Bill_Value
1    1513      Detergent.Bars 20180204      30.00
2    1513        French.Fries 20180803     160.00
3    1513  Fruit.Based.Juices 20180204      30.00
4    1513          Containers 20180803      79.00
5    1513 Candies.&.Lollypops 20180803     165.00
6    1513              Cheese 20180204     203.04
7    1513   Cleaners.&.Wipers 20180803     159.00
8    1513          Chocolates 20180803     448.00
9    1513   Frozen.Veg.Snacks 20180803     570.00
```

data:

```
 df <- read.table(text = "Cust_ID SubDepartment       Date        Bill_Value
1513    Detergent.Bars      20180204    30
           1513    French.Fries        20180803    160
           1513    Fruit.Based.Juices  20180204    30
           1513    Containers          20180803    79
           1513    Candies.&.Lollypops 20180803    165
           1513    Cheese              20180204    203.04
           1513    Cleaners.&.Wipers   20180803    159
           1513    Chocolates          20180803    448
           1513    Frozen.Veg.Snacks   20180803    570
           1860    Salted.Biscuits     20180110    40
           1860    Oats                20180705    60
           1860    Pastries            20180815    198
           1860    Cheese              20180110    85
           1860    Veg.Powdered.Soups  20180814    20
           1860    Paneer              20180123    99
           1860    North.Indian.Mixes  20180502    59
           1860    Flavoured.Milk      20180502    40", header = TRUE)
```